# How can I configure https for .onion in XAMPP?

Tags: onion-services, https

I've reviewed and reread several guides on how to make https for localhost in xampp, but replacing localhost in the configuration with my .onion name didn't help me set it up as https - it just won't load.

How do I set up https for an onion site based on XAMPP? Maybe someone has done this before?

Comment: You don't need "https" in a .onion service, just expose the plain TCP port to Tor and let the users connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS requires a signed SSL certificate. You can not use Let's Encrypt and so you will need to to buy a certificate from a provider (they are not cheap). Once you have a certificate, then you can you it with your XAMPP configuration.

If you aren't familiar with SSL certificates, then I would suggest researching that first.

One more thing, make sure your onion service is using port 443 and not port 80. If you don't use the right port, nothing can connect.